# How to secure my broadband internet connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, internet, broadband

My friend purchased broadband internet connection, but when scan network security on Avast Internet security it say that: "network router is accessible from the internet". He is using Windows 7 Ultimate.

I have tried: 
on "**Network and shearing center**" i seen that network is "**Unidentified Network**". So i go to "secpol.msc" and make privet the "**Unidentified Network**". But nothing change. I have selected Public network when first time connect on broadband internet.

My firewall is on and advance shearing setting i have Turn off **file/folder and network sharing** by selecting radio buttons. My network router is accessible from the internet. So how to secure my broadband internet connection?

Comment: If it says that the router is available from the internet, then the problem is on the router's config, not anything you have to set up in your computer. Could you share some info about your router's model?

Comment: Login to your router, and make sure that router management is disabled on the WAN. Nothing else you are doing has anything to do with the Avast scan message.

Comment: One more Question: I have selected Public network when first time connect on broadband internet. Is it ok? or should I select Home Network ?

Comment: Technically is okay but since you _are_ on a home network you _should_ choose home network.

Comment: What is the advantage between home and public ?

Comment: Windows file sharing. It'll hide devices on the LAN from each other (your laptop wont see your family members laptops and vice versa). Usually not important.